# How to iterate Map<Map, Map> over jsf..?

Tags: java, jsf

i have a map which i want to iterate over the jsf. The map is as -

```
LinkedHashMap<Map<String,String>,Map<String,String>>           propertyMap=new       LinkedHashMap<Map<String,String>,Map<String,String>>();
```

earlier i have iterated the following map on jsf of type String, String in following manner

```
 List documentProperties = new ArrayList(propertyMap.entrySet());
```

And in jsf :-

```
   <af:iterator value="#{EditProperties.documentProperties}" var="list" id="i1">
              <trh:rowLayout id="rl1">
                    <trh:cellFormat id= "cf3"><af:outputText value="#{list.key}"
                                                             id="ot1"/>   </trh:cellFormat>
                    <trh:cellFormat id= "cf4">
                        <af:inputText id="it1"
                                      value="#{list.value}" showRequired="false">
                        </af:inputText>    
                    </trh:cellFormat>
              </trh:rowLayout>
```

But how can i iterate a map having two map inside it on jsf..??
Thanks

Comment: Key of Map should be Immutable? Why are you using two maps?

Comment: A Map keyed by a Map sounds like a very bad idea ...

Comment: but my requirement is that i want to display 4 values on the jsf page from one spurce itself

Comment: Can you please give More explanation of your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` as a `key` is bad idea. You should use `Immutable` objects as key to hashmap. 
If you want to declare Map inside Map then you can do something like below.

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Map<String,Map<String,String>>> propertyMap=new LinkedHashMap<String,Map<String,Map<String,String>>>();
```

Comment: My eyes hurt from all that generics :-)